# Creating Table by using Tuple Dictionary (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have dict with tuple key:

```
td=[((1, 1), 1), ((1, 2), 2), ((1, 3), 1) ((2, 1), 1), ((2, 2), 5), ((3, 2), 2]
```

I want to create the table like below: (using tuple as index)

```
     1     2     3

1    1     2     1

2    2     5     2

3    1     0     0
```

How can I create this table by using python?

I tried pd.MultiIndex, but it was not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: `td` is a list of tuples...

Comment: FTFY the title.

Comment: Just updated the question to clarify

Comment: Is there anyway to know I need to go to out 9(ten columns and rows) or do you just want to pick 9?

Comment: just 9 for now, but later it can be changed. (I need to set this number)

Comment: I don't appreciate the fact that you completely overhauled your question. If you had a different question, you're better off writing a new post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this way .

```
pd.Series(dict(td)).reset_index()
Out[115]: 
   level_0  level_1  0
0        1        1  1
1        1        2  2
2        1        3  1
3        2        1  1
4        2        2  5
5        3        1  1
6        3        2  2
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, I have a quick question. I want fixed index (1 to 9). How can I add fixed index for both row and column.

Comment: @JakeHan  you can check this part  `reindex(index=range(1,10),columns=range(1,10))`

Comment: @Wen nice using dict and Series. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston thank man , I used to have one concern , the data converted to dict will have multiple keys , since he change his output, using dict should be safe. :-)

Comment: I rolled back the question and removed the edit. I can't stand for users editing their questions midway and invalidating peoples' answers and time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the need for `MultiIndex` here.

**Option 1**
Flatten before calling `pd.DataFrame`. You can generalise this with `*` argument unpacking -

```
pd.DataFrame([list(x) + y for x, *y in td])

   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  1  3  1
3  2  1  1
4  2  2  5
5  3  2  2
```

---

**Option 2**
Slightly more roundabout, using `pd.concat` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(td)

        0  1
0  (1, 1)  1
1  (1, 2)  2
2  (1, 3)  1
3  (2, 1)  1
4  (2, 2)  5
5  (3, 2)  2

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()), df.iloc[:, 1:]], axis=1)

   0  1  1
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  1  3  1
3  2  1  1
4  2  2  5
5  3  2  2
```

Comment: Adding a new way :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

Correct some data:

```
td=[((1, 1), 1), ((1, 2), 2), ((1, 3), 1), ((2, 1), 1), 
    ((2, 2), 5), ((3, 2), 2), ((3, 1), 1)]
```

Flatten tuples

```
l = [(i[0],i[1],v) for i,v in td]
lol = [list(e) for e in l]
```

Create and reshape dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(lol).set_index([1,0]).rename_axis([None,None]).unstack()[2]\
  .fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3
1  1  1  1
2  2  5  2
3  1  0  0
```

To expand dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(lol).set_index([1,0]).rename_axis([None,None]).unstack()[2]\
  .reindex(index=np.arange(1,10), columns=np.arange(1,10)).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0   1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
4  0   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
5  0   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
6  0   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
7  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ In what sense?  Datatypes?

Comment: For example, the `td` can have more than two elements nested. In which case, `(i[0],i[1],v)` would no longer work.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I agree but the whole idea of the list of tuple is to have (row, column), value.  A fourth or fifth term doesn't make sense for creating a 2-d array.

Comment: I'm not sure you got me. I meant to say that you could have `((1, 2, 3), 4)` as an element. Why not? In that case, you'd need `(i[0], i[1], i[2], v)` in your code.

Comment: (1,2,3),4 wouldn't generate the 2d array OP is asking for in question (In my opinion that is what he is asking).

Comment: Thanks Scott! it seems that your code is working well.  I have a quick question.  I am working with more complex list of tuples, but the code doesn't give index value if there is no tuples in the data set.  (ex. it gives index  1   2   5   6   7 , but I want 1  2  3  4  5  6   7 although there are no 3, 4 in the data set.

Comment: @JakeHan, I don't understand "doesn't give values if there is no tuples".  Can you give me an example or explain that more?

Comment: I rolled back the question and removed the edit on the answers. I can't stand for users editing their questions midway and invalidating peoples' answers and time.